# jQuery tabs bug when using it with another jQuery/JS code on some tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I am building simple site, in which I can create graph and use some algorithms on it. It is possible, that there will be many algorithms, so I have to think about way, how I will output so much data.

I have some html code (some fieldsets, inputs, buttons etc) for part of setting up graph and same for part of algorithms.

I had divided different parts to different tabs.

On first tab, where I set up graph, I have to use jQuery (to get value of inputs, to block/unblock some fields etc), on another tabs I have simple text at the moment.

The problem is: when I just had loaded page, all tabs working properly. When I click different tabs, data in div is chaging. But if I, firstly, try to create some vertexes or edges or do anything with graph and after that I will try to activate another tab, error is appearing. Look at the image, please:

[image: error]

It says:

```
TypeError: elem.nodeName.toLowerCase is not a function

var noData = elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];
```

It refers to 3378 row of `jquery-1.10.2.js` file.

**NOTE** that if I did nothing on first tab (didn't try to manage vertexes/edges/etc) and pressing on any tab all is working fine.

It is not my error. Looks like it is error of compatibility. I don't understand. Can you clarify this for me? What can cause this error and how I can remove it? Thank you.

This is `head` part of my html code:

```
<!-- for tabs -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- for graph dracula framework -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dracula_graffle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dracula_graph.js"></script>

<!-- my files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="settings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="algorithms.js"></script>

 <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work fine if I rewrite part of code around 3378 row in jquery script. Rewrited `acceptData` method:

```
// A method for determining if a DOM node can handle the data expando
acceptData: function( elem ) {
    if ( elem.nodeName ) {
        var match = false;
        if (typeof elem.nodeName.toLowerCase != 'undefined')
            match = jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

        if ( match ) {
            return !(match === true || elem.getAttribute("classid") !== match);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

If we handle error there, all working fine. It is very dirty solution, but it is just lab work, so I don't care :) I hope this answer will help somebody.